# Can't get the password screen up to log in

Tags: windows-xp

I keep having this recurring problem... I cannot get the blue password screen on the lock page to get my homepage up. The wire I have is connected to a secondary screen because my laptop screen is broken. The cord is a little loose but that's not the problem it says No Signal then goes to a black screen.... but my router for wireless is lit and on.

What is this problem and how do I fix it? The laptop is a dell espirion with Windows XP. Sometimes I can get in because the blue password screen comes up and other times I can't and it so very frustrating.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! I feel like it's just broken, you should get it repaired or buy a new one.

Answer (score 0):

If the "No signal" is like one of my LCD computer monitors, then that message is displayed locally by the monitor, and indicates that the PC is not properly connected.  So that loose cable could very well be the problem, rather than a wireless network issue.  Fix that issue before progressing on to the log in screen.

Why is the video cable a "little loose"?